# Phonegap camera & QR

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera, qr-code

Currently i'm just started the phonegap project which purposed to scan the QR code and decode into information. While doing i notice, the camera access as stated in default phonegap documentation is click the button, open the default camera app, capture the image, and back to application with the image.

Is it possible to direct call a "live" camera on the application itself like others QR scanning application? Without clicking the capture button?

Im using jsqrcode library to decode the QR code. Please advice if there is any better plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we use this phonegap plugin:

[PhoneGap Plugin BarcodeScanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner)

It scans "on the fly" while the camera app is active. It works with QR Codes.

> Supported Platforms:
>
> ```
> Android
> iOS
> Windows (Windows/Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10)
> Windows Phone 8
> BlackBerry 10
> Browser
> ```